# Converting from TAI modified Julian Day to Datetime

Tags: python, datetime, astropy

I'm trying to convert from TAI modified Julian Day to datetime (and vice versa).

I've been going through astropy's `Time()` documentation and I've gotten close:

```
from astropy.time import Time

constantOffset = 2430000
input1 = 27754.500428240735  # corresponds to 2017-01-01 00:00:00 in TAIMJD
input2 = 27253.500416666669  # corresponds to 2015-08-19 00:00:00 in TAIMJD

t1 = Time(input1 + constantOffset, format='jd')
print(t1.datetime)  # 2017-01-01 00:00:37
t2 = Time(input2 + constantOffset, format='jd')
print(t2.datetime)  # 2015-08-19 00:00:36
```

What's going wrong here is that there is a changing offset based on the year - see http://maia.usno.navy.mil/ser7/tai-utc.dat

I've played around with adding the parameter `scale='tai'` into the declarations for `Time` objects but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Does anybody see a way to account for the unsteady offset?

Could be helpful - http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/time/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing TAI and UTC time scales.  The default time `scale` in `astropy.time.Time` is `UTC` but you are feeding in JD times relative to `TAI`.  Here is the result you probably expected:

```
>>> t1 = Time(input1 + constantOffset, format='jd', scale='tai')
>>> t1_utc = t1.utc
>>> t1_utc.iso
'2017-01-01 00:00:00.000'
>>> t1_utc.datetime
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what `iso` is?

Comment: The `.iso` property just returns a [`TimeISO`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.time.TimeISO.html#astropy.time.TimeISO) instance.